# Can I use PowerShell with SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, powershell

I know SQL Server 2008 has exposed some features to PowerShell as snapins. Now I want to know whether I can use PowerShell with SQL Server 2005? I guess the answer is **NO**, right? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes -- You can use PowerShell with SQL Server 2005. The SQL Server 2008 minishell, sqlps.exe, which ships with SQL Server 2008 works against 2005 and even 2000 servers.

To get sqlps you'll need to either install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio or sqlps is available as a separate download as part of the [SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=c6c3e9ef-ba29-4a43-8d69-a2bed18fe73c)

In addition you can write PowerShell code directly using SQL Server Management Objects (SMO). SMO is the underlying classes used in SSMS and sqlps and was first introduced in SQL Server 2005. Like sqlps, SMO will work against SQL Server 2000.

The CodePlex project I coordinate, [SQL Server PowerShell Extensions](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/), provides over 130 functions and uses SMO and PowerShell that work with 2000 through 2008 R2 versions of SQL Server.